# How to install Python 3.4 on Ubuntu when Python 3.5 is already installed

Tags: apt, python

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 installed, which has Python 3.5 installed. So when I run `python3`, Python 3.5 is running. I need to install Python 3.4 (since this is the latest version that the Pygame module supports).

How can I install Python 3.4 onto this machine? Do I have to uninstall Python 3.5? How do I run Python 3.4 if python3 runs 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install Python 3.4 because there's a version of pygame ready for 3.5. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install pygame
```

The last command gives the output:

```
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-1.9.2rc1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 10.0MB 54kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame
```

Note the `cp35`, which means it's for Python 3.5. This can be verified:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
>>>
```

Note the lack of an error when importing it.

---

Credit to [another answer dealing with the same problem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40721621/7208029).